# Webpack - Dynamically importing a class

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, es6-modules, dynamic-import

I'm trying to dynamically import a class when a router condition is met.

I have no problems importing a standard (non-class) module, as this works as expected:

```
Router.on({
    '/:region/map': (params) => {
      import("Controllers/map.js" /* webpackChunkName: "map" */).then(({map}) => {
        map.initialise(params.region);
      });
    }
});
```

But trying to do the same with a class is not working as expected.

```
Router.on({
    '/:region/map': (params) => {
      import("Controllers/map.js" /* webpackChunkName: "map" */).then(Map => {
        Map.initialise(params.region);
      });
    }
});
```

Which fails 'e.initialise is not a function';

I also try to instantiate the class by using the `new` keyword:

```
Router.on({
    '/:region/map': (params) => {
      import("Controllers/map.js" /* webpackChunkName: "map" */).then(Map => {
        const MapClass = new Map();
        MapClass.initialise(params.region);
      });
    }
});
```

But still no joy!

How do I dynamically import a class in this scenario?

**UPDATE:**

This is my Map module, as a non-class module, which works:

```
var map = {
    initialise(region) {
        console.log("Map initialised for region: " + region);
    }
}
export { map };
```

This is the same module but as a Class:

```
export default class Map {
    constructor() {
        //
    }
    initialise(region) {
        console.log("Map initialised for region: " + region);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also share map.js code. want to see how you export from and what you export from map.js

Comment: @MohitTilwani - added. Thanks.

Comment: Was this question solved? I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 2):

```
  class Map {
    constructor() {
        //
    }
    initialise(region) {
        console.log("Map initialised for region: " + region);
    }
  } 

     export { Map }




      Router.on({
        '/:region/map': (params) => {
          import("Controllers/map.js").then(({ Map })=> {
            const MapClass = new Map();
            MapClass.initialise(params.region);
          });
        }
      });
```

can you try the above code and see are you getting Class in console

Comment: Thanks, Mohit. When I do this I get: `ƒ n(){!function(n,e){if(!(n instanceof e))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}(this,n),this.currentRegion=null}`

Comment: can you try now. I edited the above answer. Also if it doesn't work, always try consoling the things from backwards. Like what are you getting in module and all