# javascript dynamically import a class module and get the name of the class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class

This question is about chrome browser.

I am trying to dynamically import a javascript module defined as a class.

```
// data-table.js
export class DataTable extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    static get tagName() {
        return 'data-table';
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the name of the imported class in the the target code.
here is my target code that does not work.

```
// router.js
...//some code
if(route === matched){
   // dynamically import the component
   import(route.component) 
    .then( module => {
      // anyway to get classname DataTable here??
    
 })
 };
...//rest of the code
```

Here is obvious implementation that works, (because I hardcoded the module class name)

```
// router.js
...//some code
if(route === matched){
   // dynamically import the component
   import("components/data-table.js") 
    .then( {DataTable} => {
     cost t = DataTable.tagName;
     // code to handle module stuff
 })
 };
...//rest of the code
```

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785992/webpack-dynamically-importing-a-class) without any working answer, but that is about webpack and I am trying this directly in browser.
Why would I want to get the class name?
Because that gives me ability to simplify code.

Comment: Why would you try to import a class that you don't even know? Why do you even name the class?

Comment: it is a router implementation effort. when a route is matched, I would like to import the corresponding class and run it. as the whole matching part is dynamic, it is unknown beforehand which class will be needed in the router.

Comment: The route definition that the user passes to your router then should contain the class name to use. Or if all you have is a list of modules, make sure that each of the modules implements the same interface - namely a default export.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's generally a good idea (see [@Steven's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66565760/7575111)) but to answer the question:

```js
import("foo").then(module => {
    let name = Object.keys(module)[0];
});
```

Certainly not the best way to do it, but a solution nonetheless. 
This only works for single exports in the form of `export class ...`.

Answer (score 7):

When using a default export with dynamic imports, you need to destructure and rename the "default" key from the returned object.

```js
import(route.component)
    .then(({ default: DataTable }) => { 
        console.log(DataTable.tagName);
    });
```

I just ran into this same problem, but I'm using async / await in Node:

```js
const { default: myClass } = await import('/path/to/class.js');
```

This allowed me to access the static property methods of the myClass object.

Comment: This would be a correct answer if the module used a default export. But it does not

Comment: IMHO, if there's only one export in a file, it should be a default export. Anyway, I hope my answer helps anyone who runs into the same issue I had. It took me a while to figure out how to destructure it correctly.

Comment: Very fair, and this does help others that will find the question through search so I've very belatedly given you the +1 I should have the first time 

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you're already destructuring `{DataTable}` (your syntax is wrong, it needs to be `({DataTable})`) shows that it's a key in the module, equivalent to `module.DataTable` or `module['DataTable']`. So you already have it that way. If you really know the name `DataTable` at dev-time, then you already have a string.

But presumably you don't know the name, or it's exposed under a common name, such as `export const Component = DataTable`, at which point you have a consistent way to access it: `module.Component`.

In either case, as long as you have the class object, it's just a function, which has the property `.name`, so you can always just do `DataTable.name === 'DataTable'`.

But in my professional opinion, metaprogramming like this to save a little work leads to fragile code that almost always breaks inconveniently at some point.